# Regular expression in Javacscript Validation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have one text box where as user will enter the year (ex: 2017-17) format.i want to validated the text box value in on key press event, my scenario as fallows

1) First 4 characters should be an Integers

2) 5th character should be "-".

3) Last two characters should be Integers .

Thanks.

Comment: Here you go: /\d{4}-\d{2}/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match it against a regular expression with the wanted condition (four digits, a hyphen and two digits).

```
/\d{4}-\d{2}/.test(string);
```

or

```
string.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}/);
```

Example:

```js
console.log(/\d{4}-\d{2}/.test('2017-17'));
console.log(/\d{4}-\d{2}/.test('aa17-17'));
console.log('2017-17'.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}/));
console.log('aa17-17'.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}/));
```